# Умеет ли ModelMapper удалять элементы коллекции приемника?

Tags: java, dto

Коллеги, можно ли средствами `ModelMapper` удалять ставшие лишними элементы коллекции приемника?
Есть связь OneToMany:  Employee - Contact.
В контроллер в метод `update` приходит объект `еmployeeDTO` со связанным `contactsDTO`.
И если в источнике `еmployeeDTO.contactsDTO` элементов меньше чем в приемнике `еmployee.contacts`, то нужно чтобы лишние элементы удалялись в приемнике. Т.е. состав приемника должен повторить состав источника, сопоставляя элементы по id.

Можно ли реализовать это удаление этим вызовом: `modelMapper.map(employeeDTO, employee)` ?
Насколько я знаю, у ModelMapper большие возможности конвертации.

```
{    
    "id": 27,
    "firstName": "Ivan",
    "birthday": "2000-11-16",
    "contacts":
    [
        {"id": 32,
         "value":"322-223",
        "type": "PHONE"
        },
        {"id": 33,
         "value":"111-555",
        "type": "PHONE"
        },
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modelMapper.getConfiguration().setCollectionsMergeEnabled(false)